# Replace ONLY first occurrence of word from a paragraph using RegEx

Tags: regex

I have two paragraphs. I want to replace ONLY first occurrence of a specific word '**acetaminophen**' by '*{yootooltip :: It is a widely used over-the-counter analgesic (pain reliever) and antipyretic (fever reducer). Excessive use of paracetamol can damage multiple organs, especially the liver and kidney.}acetaminophen{/yootooltip}*'

The paragraph is:
*Percocet is a painkiller which is partly made from oxycodone and partly made from **acetaminophen**. It will usually be prescribed for a patient who is suffering from acute severe pain. Because it has oxycodone in it, this substance can create an addiction and is also a dangerous prescription drug to abuse. It is illegal to either sell or use Percocet that has not been prescribed by a licensed professional.
In 2008, drugs like Percocet (which have both oxycodone and **acetaminophen** as their main ingredients) were the prescription drugs most sold in all of Ontario. The records also show that the rates of death by oxycodone (this includes brand name like Percocet) doubled. That is why it is imperative that the people who are addicted go to an Ontario drug rehab center. Most of the drug rehabs can take care of Percocet addiction.*

I am trying to write a regular expression for this. I have tried
\bacetaminophen\b
But it is replacing both occurrences. 
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: I can't use any php function. I wan the reg expression for matching the first occurance.

Comment: Then WHY is your question tagged with `PHP`?

Comment: So many +1s for you, @Madbreaks. Except I've over-voted today. :-(

Comment: In which programming language are you trying to find the solution?

Comment: I've given you the correct RegEx in my answer, however until you tell us how you intend to *apply* the RegEx, the answer will vary.  So -- how are you applying the RegEx?  Not by PHP, then using...?

Comment: Regex flavors vary. In Javascript, for example **RegExp** does not have any kind of lookbehind (which can be replicated by alternative approaches) whereas RegEx in PHP does have these. So we need to know the programming language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the optional `$limit` parameter in PHP's `preg_replace` function https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

```
$text = preg_replace('/acetaminophen/i', 'da-da daa', $text, 1);
```

will replace only the first occurance.

Comment: Rewording someone else's answer won't get you rep points faster, Milo.

Comment: I don't care about points. I had written nearly the whole thing with `preg_replace` rather than `str_replace` until you brought up the point that regex isn't needed.

Answer (score 0):

For [the tool you're using](http://www.pagecolumn.com/tool/regtest.htm), just use this:

```
(.*?)\bacetaminophen\b
```

Comment: Sorry it didn't worked. I have tested at http://www.pagecolumn.com/tool/regtest.htm

Comment: d'oh! forgot a `*`, fixed.  Note that after you do the replace, you'll need to restore the parentheses values with `$1` and `$2`.  What are you using to apply the regex?

Comment: Sorry but it still giving no match found.

Comment: when i am applying (.*?)\bacetaminophen\b(.*) then whole paragraph gets replaced

Comment: @SubhenduKumarMukherjee Updated just so I can cater to the specific tool you're using to test.  The RegEx is correct.  Tested on your sample, it does match properly.  Make sure to remove the `g` option that that page wants to apply to the RegEx, as that means "replace all".

Comment: Do you know anything about regular expressions? If so, see my comment above about `$1` and `$2`.  If not, well, I'd suggest you read up (no offense intended).  Again, the RegEx is correct.  I've updated one more time to simplify it.

Comment: I have removed g flag, but it is still replacing whole paragraph

Comment: The problem is not the RegEx, it's your understanding of how to use that (rather poor IMO) testing tool.

Comment: Tell us (e.g. update your original question) *exactly* what you are entering in each field of that testing tool.  I don't know what you're entering, but you are doing something wrong.

Comment: Sorry Sir. But when I use (.*?)\bacetaminophen\b and in flag nothing, then it is replacing the line containing first occurrence. But good news is it replaces only first occurrence now.

Comment: As suggested here is what i am entering in the tool.RegEx Pattern:(.*?)\bacetaminophen\b     flag empty    select method replace    replace text: the above mentioned in quesiton